# Using pymongo in a firewalled system

Tags: mongodb, port, pymongo, firewall

I'd like to use pymongo to interact with the atlas mongodb cloud server from the community server, but the community server only allows 80 and 443 port for the outbound data. Can I make connection to atlas mongodb cloud server for such system?

Currently I'm trying to connect to the atlas server by:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient("mongodb://<id>:<password>@<server address>:<port>")
```

but I get the time out error.